# Reduce padding after figure

Tags: spacing, floats

I want to reduce the padding between figures and text. I know I can achieve this using `\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-7pt}` but this will reduce the padding of all figures. How can I accomplish this only for certain figures?

Comment: Could you please post a code reproducing your problem?

Comment: Since you haven't provided the code source, you can simply use `~\\[10pt]` (or whatever the appropriate spacing amount) right after your `\end{figure}`.

Comment: To locally change the value of `\belowcaptionskip` use it inside of the `figure` environment.

Comment: Add `\vspace{<len>}` (where `<len>` is negative) before your `\caption`.

Comment: Just in case: wouldn't this padding due to using `\begin{figure}\begin{center} ... \end{center}\end{figure}`, instead of `\begin{figure}\centering ... \end{figure}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert a negative `\vspace` at the end of the image insertion - this will result in moving the caption up by the given amount, visually "reducing" the image size.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=10\baselineskip]{example-image-a}
  \caption{This is a figure caption.}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-7]

\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=10\baselineskip]{example-image-b}
  \vspace{-5\baselineskip}% Reduce image height
  \caption{This is a figure caption.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The same can be achieved with [`adjustbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) using its `vspace = <above> <below>` option.

```
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
% ...
\includegraphics[vspace=0pt -5\baselineskip,height=10\baselineskip]{example-image-b}
```

This can be done an a figure-by-figure basis.